# Wrapping submit button in label element for cross browser compatibility and styling

Tags: css, button, input, uibutton, submit

Hi all I have been looking around as I am fed up with the lack of compatibility for styling submit buttons.

I was looking at no other than facebook themselves source.

They do something like this:

```
<label class="uiButton uiButtonLarge Post">
<input type="submit" value="Post" />
</label>
```

They set the css display for the label as an `inline-block` and then set padding etc..

Is this the best way to do it?

Or is there an even better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/03/35-essential-submit-button-enhancements.html

This tutorials should be fine, sure they're not identical with FB but there are crossbrowser stylings to pure css. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the article link but this doesn't really answer my question above :)